# Can't install Guest Additions - (Missing 'Devices' Menu on host)

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

The top menu is wrong (Virtualbox 4.2, Windows 7)

Shows: File, Machine, Help

Expected: File, Machine, **Devices**, Help

[image]

Comment: How did you get OSX in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to hit HOST + C to disable stretched display (Right-Control C) and the Devices menu was shown on the Guest window NOT on the Virtual Box window.

Answer (score 9):

When in seamless/fullscreen mode, you can hit `Host` + `Home` key to popup the toolbar dialog menu.

I know this post is old/may not have been a hotkey at the time, but figured for people visiting trying to find this (as it's high up on search results) it may be helpful!

Comment: What, exactly, does this have to do with the “Devices” menu not appearing on the menu bar?

Comment: @Scott it will pop up the guest machines menu when it is hidden

Comment: What is the equivalent fo macos?

Answer (score 3):

Please update to the latest version of VirtualBox, version 4.3.26. The Devices menu will normally only be shown at the top of the virtual machine window when a virtual machine is running. You can also also use the keyboard shortcut to insert the Guest Additions CD. By default, to do this, hold down the Ctrl key on the right right of your keyboard, and hit the "D" key.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with MAC host and Ubuntu guest. Finally, I found this:

1. Go to preferences.
2. Select "input"->"Virtual Machine"
   Add shortcut key to "Menu Bar Settings" (I added HOST key + M)

[image: Screenshot]

3. Click "OK" and go to running virtual machine and press the key combination for Menu Bar Settings. Then you can see menu on top of the screen

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:** " Devices menu not visible"

**Resolution:**

Your  => Settings => User Interface => Tab "Device"

Make sure each of the menus are ticked ...

[image: Show Ticked Boxes]

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Discovered that right clicking  empty space in the Menu panel will cause a subset bar to show up. Clicking on "Devices" will add it to the main menu bar. Don't know why it's hidden in the first place- wasn't in earlier versions of VM. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue just now. Following are my findings:-

Issue: " Devices menu not visible"

Resolution:

There is actually an option as to what you want to see in the menu for  a machine.
 Make sure 'Devices' is selected here.

[image]

Comment: There is no "devices" in your screenshot.  Please explain your answer in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to settings> user interface
2. click the option device
3. click ok.
4. to start the machine, click start.
5. in the OS that you installed, press <kbd>host</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

   you will see the option above will appear.

Answer (score 0):

In the VM respective machine (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) General / User Interface must be selected Device like others tabs (File Machine etc Help) and in each one select what you want (Insert Guest Additions CD Image) The you will see the CD and from there install the additional modules with:
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Answer (score -1):

The Menu Settings can be accessed in the 'Settings' (R-Click the VM) then 'User interface' (Tab) 
Make sure each of the menus are ticked and are slightly greyed and OK and then start/restart VM.
This applies to the MAC Version but something similar should work for the other platforms.